# Suggestion/intellisense does not work on Visual Studio Code Version:1.21.1. Is there any workout for this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

So I have just installed the latest version of the Visual Studio Code from its website. But the autocomplete/suggestion does not work for my javascript code. Can Someone help

[image]

Comment: Do you have npm installed?

Comment: @Mark Yes have npm installed.